# "Cannot find module './something.module.scss' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, module

I'm trying to use scss modules with react typescript. This feature should be baked into React from react-scripts@2.0.0 and higher as it says on their [website](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/).

For typescript support and intellisense, I am using the *typescript-plugin-css-modules* module.

Hovering over css imports for classnames work just fine:

[image: hovering over css import, with intellisense classnames showing up]

Here's my code:

---

#### src/pages/homePage/homePage.tsx

```js
import styles from './styles.module.scss';
 
const HomePage = () => {
    return <div className={styles.myStyle}>Home page</div>;
};
    
export default HomePage;
```

---

#### src/pages/homePage/styles.module.scss

```css
.myStyle {
    color: red;
}
```

---

#### Error message on screen:

[image: error message on website]

As you can see, the color is correct in the background, and dismissing the error makes the website work just fine. Therefore, it is safe to assume that the error is only made by typescript. I have seen articles about this, like [this one](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2020/06/22/css-module-typescript/#comment-680455) where they declare a style.d.ts file in the module root dir, for declaring css modules, with something like this inside:

```js
// For SCSS
declare module "*.module.scss" {
  const classes: { [key: string]: string };
  export default classes;
}
```

However, this produces an error as classes is already defined, because this file is already created by react scripts:

##### node_modules/react-scripts/lib/react-app.d.ts

```js
[...]

declare module '*.module.scss' {
  const classes: { readonly [key: string]: string };
  export default classes;
}

[...]
```

So, since react-scripts already create these for me, and I am using the *typescript-plugin-css-modules* module, everything should be fine. I am not receiving any red lines or errors in the code editor, only in the website.

I hope someone has a solution, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer. I accidentally deleted react-app-env.d.ts after using create-react-app. This must exist in order to use CSS modules. If your project is also missing this file. Add it to your src folder and write

```js
/// <reference types="react-scripts" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can use module.scss but u should import style from module.css, not module.scss. It works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am importing styles, as the default export. If i try to destructure the import (which is what I believe you are referring to), I will reach the individual css classes. That is what my testing has proven at least ...